# Regular expression matching of the contents of text files in a directory

Tags: python, regex

I have a directory of text files. I need to set a status for each file based on whether it matches 1, both or neither regex patterns. My plan is:

1. Walk directory
2. If the file's content:

   - does not match either pattern, status = 1
   - matches pattern1 BUT NOT pattern2, status = 2
   - matches pattern2 BUT NOT pattern1, ignore
   - matches pattern1 AND pattern2, status = 3
3. Print file name and status

My code:

```py
pattern1 = re.compile(r'critical', re.IGNORECASE)
pattern2 = re.compile(r'gouting bile', re.IGNORECASE)

for file in os.listdir('/home/ea/medical'):
    if re.findall(pattern1, file) and re.findall(pattern2, file):
        status = 3
        print(file, "Status: ", status)
    elsif re.findall(pattern1, file) and not re.findall(pattern2, file):
        status = 2
        print(file, "Status: ", status)
    else:
        status = 1
        print(file, "Status: ", status)
```

My issue is that this doesn't return anything.

Comment: What if it contains pattern 2 but not pattern 1?

Comment: You don't need to use `findall()`. You only need to know if there's at least one match, so just use `re.search()`.

Comment: @Barmar - Not a condition we care about. Thank you for asking!

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: It doesn't return anything at all.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Are you aware that your code has invalid syntax? If you're looking for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including valid code, input, expected output, and actual output. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: You're not reading the files, you're just matching the patterns against the filenames.

Comment: Is there a way to check a file without iterating over each line? I thought findall would do that.

Comment: What gave you that impression? The second argument to `re.findall()` is a string, it returns all the matches of the pattern found in that string. How is it supposed to know that the string is a filename and it should read the file?

Comment: Not to mention that `file` doesn't even contain the directory. So even if it did read the file, it wouldn't know where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read the files, you're just checking the patterns against the filenames.

```
for file in os.listdir('/home/ea/medical'):
    contents = open(os.path.join('/home/ea/medical', file)).read()
    status = 1
    if re.search(pattern1, contents):
        status += 1
    if re.search(pattern2, contents):
        status += 1
    print(f"{file} Status: {status}")
```